# Yii2 Add model to hasMany relation in runtime

Tags: php, yii2

Is there any way to add new object to hasMany relation without refetching from DB?

I mean if I have an ActiveRecord named `FileList` which have the following relation and adder function:

```
public function getFiles()
{
    return $this->hasMany(File::className(), ['fileListId' => 'id']);
}

public function addFile()
{
    $file = new File([
        'fileListId' => $this->id
    ]);

    return $file;
}
```

Despite having the actual model in `$file`, when I try to access `$fileList->files[0]` it will be requested again from the DB.

Ofc, I've tried to make an assignment like: `$this->files[] = new File(...)` but it isn't working, because no setter is given. And even if I add new setter for this, I really don't know, what to fill in to make it work as expected.

Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your model has a relation files, or even when it does not - you could call $activeRecord->populateRelation('files',$fileModels)

see: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#populateRelation()-detail

In your case:

```
public function addFile()
{
    $file = new File([
        'fileListId' => $this->id
    ]);

    return $file;
}
```

could perhaps become

```
public function addFile()
{
    $files = [];
    $files[] = $file = new File([
        'fileListId' => $this->id
    ]);

    $this->populateRelation('files',$files);

    return $file;
}
```

Comment: Yes! That's indeed what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that! Thank you

Comment: I use this also - it's convenient to be able to load new models unto a related model and being able to reuse the instances without loading them from the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the array of ActiveRecord returned by the relations in a new property (normal one, not a db field) and use the new property.

It kinda strage in my opinion. I dont know your usecase but (assuming a normal web application) usally when the processing of the form post is finished you should make a redirect so the user cant resend the form by refreshing the page.

Comment: Yea, it would be nice workaround. Usecase is pretty simple: there is some file management going when user makes a request. Files are moving from list to list and from directories to each other. At some point I wanna know, which files are in specified list. Cos all of the files are already fetched from DB or their models created anew, I don't want additional requests to be made to fetch them again.

Comment: Oh, so in the same Yii action you need to move multiple files from a list to another and then do something with the updated informations? Then the new property is probably the way to go :) 
As this is a functionality of a specific controller i would create a variable in the action or a property in the controller holding an array of array of File and use the id of the file list as key of the outermost array.